# SQL: print the address of the publisher who has published only one book

Tags: sql

tables:

```
auth(auth, age), book(title,auth,pubname), publ(pubname,address)
```

I am attempting to come up with the query that will print the address of the publisher who has published only one book here is my attempt, please correct me if i am wrong: This is not homework, it is part of a study guide for an upcoming test.

```
SELECT address 
FROM publ 
WHERE pubname 
  IN ( SELECT pubname 
       FROM book 
       GROUP BY pubname 
         HAVING count(*) = 1)
```

I think that is right but not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inner join with group by query will solve your problem.

```
select address from from publ pb 
inner join 
(SELECT pubname 
 FROM   book 
 GROUP BY pubname 
 HAVING count(*) = 1) b
on b.pubname = pb.pubname
```

Comment: @user2345335 Yeah OK glad to help you. ::)